# Joining four tables with SQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

How can I join 4 tables and retrieve information about one ID(row)?

this is what I have so far:

Comment: What doesn't work about what you have so far?

Comment: @Undo: I would say everything

Comment: Can you please share the table structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: SELECT  Student.Student_ID, Course.Crs_Desc, Enrollment.Std_ID,Enrollment.Offer_No, Offering.Offer_No
FROM Offering, Enrollment, Course, Student                        ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined           this is the error

Comment: Use alias to avoid ambiguous columns

Comment: @ Mureinik  I have a specific student in student table with FN, LN related to Enrollment table with Std_ID and OfferNO(classes currently taking) which is related to Offering table which includes OfferNO and CourseNo which is related to CourseNO, Crs Des in Course table. I'm trying to retrieve courseNO and CrsDes on specific student.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, the problem is that you have several columns with the same name so nee to use alias:

```
SELECT  Crs_Desc, Enrollment.Enrollme,  Enrollment.Offer_No
FROM Offerin, Course
JOIN Enrollment ON Enrollment.Offer_No = Offering.Offer_No 
JOIN Student ON Student.Std_ID = Enrollment.Std_ID

WHERE Enrollment.Std_ID = '103'
GROUP BY Enrollment.Std_ID;
```

If this query do not solve your problems, share your table data and expected results

Comment: how does it know enr = enrollment table? that's part of my confusion

Comment: @extram what do you mean? The Enrollment AS enr aliases the table, allowing it to be referenced as enr throughout the query

Comment: There are no aggregating functions in this query.

Comment: FROM Offering AS off, Course, Student
              *
ERROR at line 2: 
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: It's not letting me use AS

Comment: off is a reserved word, so need to put into quotes. I edited my answer, just try it

Comment: If you post your tables definition this will be more simple

Comment: I have 5 tables how can i post it on here?

Comment: You don't need to use aliases, though they often make things clearer. The point is that you need to qualify the column names, either with aliases or the actual table names, in order to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: ORA-00911: invalid character. ---- doesn't accept 'off'

Comment: You're using `'` instead of `, @Bacs are right, aliases don't needed, so i removed from the answer to make things clear, check it

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT  Student.Student_ID, Course.Crs_Desc, 
    Enrollment.Std_ID, Enrollment.Offer_No, 
    Offering.Offer_No 
    FROM Student
        JOIN Enrollment
            ON Student.Student_ID = Enrollment.Std_ID
        JOIN Offering
            ON Enrollment.Std_ID = Offering.Offer_No
        JOIN Course
            ON Offering.Offer_No = Course.CourseNo
        WHERE Student_ID = '103';
```

Also, the WHERE clause looks like it could be wrong. try "WHERE Student_ID = '103';"

Comment: I'm getting an error for this too. ORA-00904: "STUDENT"."STUDENT_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: Yeah I jsut corrected the name but this is the error i'm getting ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression on Course.Crs_Desc

Comment: Take out the GROUP BY, you don't need it here anyway.

Comment: no error now!! but even though Student 103 is taking 3 OfferNo, no rows selected. what could that mean??

Comment: How is your Offering table related to the Course table, what columns?

Comment: What is your expected outcome? If student 103 exists in the Student table, are there associated records in the other tables? You probably need to use Student.Student_ID in your WHERE clause instead of Std_ID, and use LEFT JOINS.

Comment: Offering table includes CourseNo as foreign key. and stdID from Student table is related to Enrollment table which includes StdID and OfferNo(the number of courses the student is taking).

Comment: out come would be to get all the course taken by Student 103, and course desc which is in Course table. So Student from student table, then OfferNo related to Std_ID in Enrollment table. Then OfferNo form Offering table is related to CourseNO, and CourseDesc

Comment: I think your problem is the last JOIN clause. JOIN Course ON Offering.CourseNo = Course.(This appears to be missing!). When you ran the SQL above, what did you put in for the last JOIN? Course.*what?*

Comment: And yea I was supposed to use Student.Student_ID

Comment: I updated my answer to what I think is correct. Did you get any results?

Comment: it brought up a table with the StudentID, Crs_Des(EMPTY), StudentID(Again) Offer_No, Offer_No(Empty)

Comment: actually no rows selected with JOIN and ^^^ with LEFT JOIN

Comment: @hitch united I apreciate it bro. Just changed couple of columns and used LEFT JOIN now it works. thanks

Comment: Ahh left join. Glad you got it to work. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  Student.Student_ID
       ,Course.Crs_Desc
       ,Enrollment.Std_ID
       ,Enrollment.Offer_No
       ,Offering.Offer_No 
    FROM Student
        LEFT JOIN Enrollment
            ON Student.Student_ID = Enrollment.Std_ID
        LEFT JOIN Offering
            ON Enrollment.Std_ID = Offering.Offer_No
        LEFT JOIN Course
            ON Offering.CourseNo = Course.CourseNo
        WHERE Student.Student_ID = '103';
```

Comment: ERROR at line 10: 
ORA-01722: invalid number    a star on = Course.Course_No

Comment: What are the datatypes of Offering.CourseNo and Course.CourseNo?

Comment: The error you report doesn't make sense if both columns are VARCHAR2. You've referred to both `CourseNo` and `Course_No` columns - which are the key columns, and do the datatypes match?

Comment: Thanks man I actually got it the one above to work. Used LEFT JOIN instead and changed a couple of the columns. I really appreciate it.